# Trying to find Column value based filtering in HBase REST API

Tags: rest, hadoop, hbase, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

HI I am trying to build REST APIs for exposing data that resides in HBase. For simplicity  I am using built in HBase REST API.I am following documentation from https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_hbase_rest_api.html . I have created one API for search utility which uses Rowkey. But I am stuck at that the my remaining API's require search based on column values. The documentation suggests steps but I am not able to use it.And there are no other sources available. I found there are filtering options in HBase Java Client like singlecolumnvalue filter with utilities like substringComaparator. Like these is there any way i can apply filters in HBase REST APIs?

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_hbase_rest_api.html) you pasted show how to use scanner:

```
curl -vi -X PUT \
         -H "Accept: text/xml" \
         -H "Content-Type:text/xml" \
         -d @filter.txt \
         "http://example.com:20550/users/scanner/"
```

@stelcheck collected usage of some filters [here](https://gist.github.com/stelcheck/3979381#singlecolumnvaluefilter). So if you want to use `SingleColumnValueFilter` with hbase rest api, your `filter.txt` will be like:

```
<Scanner batch="100">
  <filter>
    {
      "type": "SingleColumnValueFilter",
      "op": "EQUAL",
      "family": "Y2Y=",
      "qualifier": "cQ==",
      "latestVersion": true,
      "comparator": {
        "type": "BinaryComparator",
        "value": "dmFsdWU5"
      }
    }
  </filter>
</Scanner>
```

This example is to find the cell with value `value9` in column `cf:q`.

**Update:**

Add example to parse filter content in command line.
If don't want to use file content as data, just parse the content in command line.
 For the example above, it will be :

```
curl -s -i -X PUT -H "Accept: text/xml" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d '<Scanner batch="100"><filter>{"type": "SingleColumnValueFilter", "op": "EQUAL", "family": "Y2Y=", "qualifier": "cQ==", "latestVersion": true, "comparator": { "type": "BinaryComparator", "value": "dmFsdWU5" } }</filter></Scanner>'  "http://example.com:20550/users/scanner/"
```

Comment: Based on column value I want to fetch entire row. Actually i want my service to be used by others. For that, everytime value needs to be changed in the 'filter.txt'. How i can achieve this at runtime?And i guess everytime value needs to be converted into Bytes .

Comment: can we use 'PUT' to retrieve values from REST API? i am a beginner and had used only 'GET' to retrieve values from REST.

Comment: @AbhijitMehetre after the put command above, you can get a scannerId. Then try to call ```curl -i -X GET -H "Accept: text/xml" "http://localhost:8080/t1/scanner/$scannerId"```, you can scan the table with your filter.

Comment: @AbhijitMehetre "How i can achieve this at runtime", you can try to fill the content of ```filter.txt``` in the commandLine, can you try it yourself or I can do that later :)

Comment: @AbhijitMehetre add example to parse filter content directly in command line, hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried the way you suggested. At last I got 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request'. Any Suggestions , always welcomed. Adding the response here: